# When using Prism on Xamarin, how can I warn if the names on the View, and ViewModel don't match?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, prism, prism-6

Prism uses MVVM style convention naming to bind a View to a ViewModel on an Xamarin application.

I recently altered some of the demo code and realized, after spending way too much time debugging, that the pagename didn't match the view.

How can I enable logging, or pre compiler warnings that such a discrepancy exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to Dan's response, you can bypass the naming convention and register the ViewModel directly with the View by using the `Container.RegisterTypeForNavigation<View, ViewModel>()` method.  This is also faster as reflection will not be used to locate the VM.

Comment: I will update my projects! Where do I send feedback on Prism? I do love it. Also, my original question(OP) made me wish for a mobile version of this nifty tool: http://nileshviradiya.blogspot.in/2014/11/debugging-routes-aspnet-mvc.html Do you think Prism would support a custom/dynamically built debugging page like that?

Comment: Prism is hosted at https://github.com/prismlibrary/prism. No, Prism will not get that :)

Answer (score 1):

Locating the ViewModel for the View is handled in the Prism Core by the ViewModelLocationProvider. You can see [here](https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Prism/Mvvm/ViewModelLocationProvider.cs) how it is implemented. If you which to override the default behavior and inject your own logging you can use that as a template and call `ViewModelLocationProvider. SetDefaultViewTypeToViewModelTypeResolver(YourCustomerLocatorFunctionHere)` in your `App.OnInitialized`.

As for any any precompile warning you'd be on your own there to write a tool.